# setInterval with updated data in React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, settimeout

I have setInterval setup to be working properly inside `componentDidMount` but the parameters are not updated. For example, the `text` parameter is the same value as when the component initially mounted, despite being changed in the UI. I've confirmed `text`'s value is correctly updated in Redux store but not being passed to `this.retrieveData(text)`. I suspect the `const { text } = this.props` set the value in componentDidMount, which forbids it from updating despite it being different. How would I go about this issue?

Code below is an example, but my real use-case is retrieving data based on search criteria. Once the user changes those criteria, it will update with the new result. However, I'm unable to pass those new criteria into `componentDidMount` so the page would refresh automatically every few seconds.

```
class App extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      const { text } = this.props       //Redux store prop
      setInterval(() => this.retrieveData(text), 3000)
   }

   retrieveData = (text) => {
      let res = axios.post('/search', { text })
      updateResults(res.data)           //Redux action
   }

   render() {
      const { text, results } = this.props
      
      return (
          <input text onChange={(e) => updateText(e.target.value)} />
          <div>
              {results.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>}
          </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `componentDidMount` and `setTimeout` methods your `retrieveData` is called only once with initial value of the text. If you would like to do it in your current way please use `componentDidUpdate` method which will be called each time the props or state has changed. You can find more information about lifecycle here https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/.

If you would like to use `setInterval` just like in the question, you just need to access props inside of `retrieveData` method instead of using an argument.

```js
retrieveData = () => {
    let res = post("/search", { text: this.props.text });
    updateResults(res); //Redux action
  };
```

You can find working example for both cases here https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-blackburn-khiim?file=/src/index.js

The best solution for async calls would be to use some kind of middleware like https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk or https://redux-saga.js.org/.

You have also small issue with `input`, it should be:

```js
<input type="text" value={text} onChange={(e) => updateText(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: I corrected setTimeout to setInterval in the original post. If I leave setInterval in componentDidMount, it will be called at the correct intervals but the data being passed is incorrect. Then I tried using componentDidUpdate but the update event quickly bubbled up out of control, because `updateResults` in `this.retrieveData` updates the component, causing `componentDidUpdate` to be fired with `this.retrieveData` and the cycle goes on. The number of requests seem to be going on exponentially.

Comment: @SimonWong I just updated my answer and codesanbox for the case with `setInterval`. I believe that using `componentDidUpdate` without `setInterval` would be a better approach because setInterval will call API even when the text didn't change.

Comment: I actually need it to update whether or not something has changed. This is because when new data is made in the backend from another system, I need it to update in this application without the user having to refresh.

Comment: Ok. So I guess accessing the props inside of `retriveData` will do the work.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought about it that way. Realistically, retrieveData accepts 6 parameters and is called again in each of the filter criteria. I guess as long as I call `updateText` before `retrieveData`, the `text` prop in retrieveData will be updated appropriately before the POST request.

Comment: Actually I don't think this solution works in my case. I have a lot of business logic where I pass null to some parameters to render the correct results, meaning I have to pass the values as parameters. The workaround would be to manually set all the parameters to null but that would be very messy, such as `updateText(null)`, `updateDate(null)`, etc.

Comment: Without knowing the full context it will be hard for me to help you with anything more.